# Install pexpect error

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to to install pexpect so that I can ssh to my AppleTV and issue a "reboot" command.  I have a mac running High Sierra if that matters.  On my mac, I ran:

```
easy_install pip
```

and got:

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Best match: pip 9.0.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/11/b6/abcb525026a4be042b486df43905d6893fb04f05aac21c32c638e939e447/pip-9.0.1.tar.gz#md5=35f01da33009719497f01a4ba69d63c9
Processing pip-9.0.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-xNq5v6/pip-9.0.1/setup.cfg
Running pip-9.0.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-xNq5v6/pip-9.0.1/egg-dist-tmp-_KEhrq
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.mailmap'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'pip/_vendor/Makefile'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'contrib'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tasks'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tests'
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
Extracting pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Adding pip 9.0.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

Then I ran:

```
pip install pexpect
```

and got:

```
Collecting pexpect
  Downloading pexpect-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect)
  Downloading ptyprocess-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: ptyprocess, pexpect
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ptyprocess-0.5.2.dist-info'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Is there an other way to ssh in and issue a reboot command?